# Excluding IP addresses from a print statement

Tags: python, json

I have the following print statement that returns json like this

```
groups = {key : list(set(items)) for (key, items) in groups.iteritems() }
print(self.json_format_dict(groups, pretty=True))

{
....
  "role_1": [
    "10.1.1.1",
    "hostname1",
    "hostname2",
    "10.1.1.2"
  ]
}
```

And I have the regex '\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$' to match IP addresses.

I'm not familiar enough with python to actually put these pieces together so that my json return does NOT include any IP addresses. I'm not even sure how to search the documentation for how to do this. I think groups is an object in this case and all the examples I've seen have been for working with literal strings.

Normally I would pipe the output through sed to get what I need, but in this case it needs to all be handled in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, pass each list containing hostnames and IPs to

```
import re

def filterIP(fullList):
    regexIP = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$')
    return [i for i in fullList if not regexIP.match(i)]
```

and that should filter out the items that are IPs.

So in your case to print out the filtered dictionary you could use

```
groups = {key : filterIP(list(set(items))) for (key, items) in groups.iteritems() }
print(self.json_format_dict(groups, pretty=True))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Could you explain a bit of how this actually works? I had seen a few references to re.compile when I was looking earlier, but I didn't really understand what it was doing.

Comment: `re.compile('yourPatternHere')` basically creates a regex object from a specified pattern that can be reused with the `search()` and `match()` functions. See more at the bottom of this page: https://regexone.com/references/python